# How to dynamically generate div id in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, selector

I have a feeling this is going to be one of those bone-headed questions. But, it has me scratching my head.

I have a partial that creates a series of divs with unique ids based on object ids:

```
<% @contact.email_addresses.each do |email_address| %>
    <div id=<%= "email_address_"+email_address.id.to_s %>>
    .
    . do stuff
    .
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me a series of divs that look like this:

```
<div id="email_address_13">
  foo@bar.com
  <div class="form_icon" title="edit email address" rel="tooltip" ,="">
    <a data-remote="true" href="/email_addresses/13/edit?contact_id=2">
      <img height="11" width="11" src="/assets/mini_icons/fat_pencil.png" alt="Fat_pencil">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="form_icon" title="delete email address" rel="tooltip" ,="">
    <a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/email_addresses/13?contact_id=2">
      <img height="9" width="9" src="/assets/mini_icons/remove.png" alt="Remove">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in each div there is an edit and cancel button. So far, so good.

When the user clicks on the edit button, I want to replace the content of the div with a form that allows editing. So, in my edit.js.erb file, I want:

```
$('#email_address_13').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'email_address_form')%>")
```

So, here's the question. In my edit.js.erb file, how do I concatenate `email_address_` with my `email_address.id` so that I end up with the selector that looks like `'#email_address_13'`?

When I hard-code `'#email_addres_13'`, everything works beautifully. so this is just really a question about how to dynamically generate my div selector inside my `edit.js.erb` file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it... Turns out one line of code in edit.js.erb does the whole thing.

In terms of the concatenation, the trick is:

`$('#email_address_<%= @email_address.id.to_s %>')`

Since this is in an .erb file, I can use `<%= @email_address.id.to_s %>` to grab the `id` (converting it from integer to string along the way). This needs to go inside of $() or a `.html is not a function` error gets thrown. So, the whole call is:

`$($('#email_address_<%= @email_address.id.to_s %>')).html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'email_address_form')%>");`

There's no need to bind the click event since the button is part of a form. By definition, when the button is clicked, it triggers the controller method (`edit`) and the associated javascript file (`edit.js.erb`).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not a ruby-on-rails programmer, but actually I thought this approach (the one you suggested here) was the simplest solution, and I thought maybe you're not allowed to do so for technical/design reasons. In the other hand, my WEB-Guru once told me never EVER mix server side scripts with client side scripts. I have to say that now  I totally agree with him, though again I'm not sure what is the right approach when writing in Ruby. Anyway, good luck! and thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I would've add the id to the icon img and concatenate it in the javascript level. Your HTML will look like this (I've added id and class to the edit icon):

```
<div id="email_address_13">
    foo@bar.com
    <div class="form_icon" title="edit email address" rel="tooltip" ,="">
        <a data-remote="true" href="/email_addresses/13/edit?contact_id=2">
           <img id="13" class="edit" height="11" width="11" src="/assets/mini_icons/fat_pencil.png" alt="Fat_pencil">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="form_icon" title="delete email address" rel="tooltip" ,="">
        <a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/email_addresses/13?contact_id=2">
            <img height="9" width="9" src="/assets/mini_icons/remove.png" alt="Remove">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, your edit js function will look something like that:

```
$(".edit").click( function() {
    var id = $(this).id;
    $('#email_address_' + id).html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'email_address_form')%>")
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Naama. 

When I (a) make the changes you suggest and (b) hard code `'#email_address_13'`, then on the first click of the button nothing happens and on the second click the div replaces correctly. I suspect the click function doesn't bind until the first click (and the associated javascript) completes.  

More importantly, if I use the `'email_address_' + id'` construct, then nothing ever happens. So, I infer that the concatenation is not working correctly.

I'm going to keep plugging and if I figure it out, I'll post the answer. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to div

```
<% @contact.email_addresses.each do |email_address| %>
    <div class='your-class' id=<%= "email_address_"+email_address.id.to_s %>>
    .
    . do stuff
    .
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And in edit.js using class selector instead id selector

```
$('.your-class').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'email_address_form')%>")
```

`